# Exit from the game to desktop

Tags: pc, assassins-creed-origins

Is there a neat way to exit from the game to the desktop? Ideally something which performs proper shutdown, rather than <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.

I find it frustrating having to exit to the main title screen, waiting for that to load, and then having to exit to desktop.

So I'm looking for a way to shutdown the game without having to load the main menu.

Comment: I have included a PC tag, as that is my playing platform. If the issue is also present on consoles, please remove the tag.

Comment: Task manager may be a workaround but that may be a little risky.

Comment: I find this is an annoying problem in a lot of games.  You press "Exit" and it loads the title screen (which sometimes then requires you to press some other button to get past the intro/start screen, wait for it to load the menu, then usually get asked "Are you sure you want to quit?!?!?!") and that really bugs me.  Doesn't help solve your problem obviously; but I really appreciate when devs make it easy to exit their games.

Comment: In related news Destiny 2 has ALT+ESC to exit directly to desktop which is a nice touch.

Comment: @DavidYell it's `SHIFT+ESC`, but that's irrelevant, I guess :P

Comment: I remembe the "joy" of the initial AC (the only one I played on PC). From ingame, you exited back to Desmond in the Animus. Then you exit the Animus, which takes a lengthy animation of Desmond getting up slowly and feeling woozy. Then you exit the game, bringing you to the main menu. You must pick a profile to load. Then, after you've loaded your profile, you could exit the game. Alt F4 was the only reasonable way to quit the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the latest update you can now exit straight from the game just go to the pause menu (ESC) and then select "Quit to Desktop". This is a part of [patch 1.1.0](https://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/1804406-Assassin-s-Creed-Origins-1-1-0-Patch-Notes-Forums).

> [PC] Added “Quit to Desktop” option to the pause menu